# Why does set state not work within a subscription to an observable?

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, react-hooks

The code below has a function displayQuotes, which imports an observable that "next" are quotes. With each new quote, I would like to update the state of the quotes using react hooks. I created a custom hook that takes in an observable, subscribes it, and with each new value, sets state. I am finding that, although I log all the new incoming quotes, it appears that my setState never gets called after the first time. Any suggestions as to why this behavior is happening?

code:

```
const UseCustomHookForObservable = (observable, setState) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    let subscription=observable.subscribe((value) => {
      setState(value);
    });

    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
  }, [observable, setState]);
};

function DisplayQuotes() {
  const [storedQuotes, setQuotes] = useState({});
  UseCustomHookForObservable(SymbolsObservable, setQuotes);

  return (
    <div>
      <QuotesTable values={storedQuotes} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

What is even stranger to me is that the following does work:

```
function DisplayQuotes() {
  return (
    <div>
      <RenderSubscribedValues
        observable={SymbolsObservable}
        component={QuotesTable}
      />
    </div>
  );

class RenderSubscribedValues extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.observable = props.observable;
    this.component = props.component;
    this.state = { storedValues: {} };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.subscription = this.observable.subscribe((value) =>
      this.setState({ storedValues: value })
    );
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
  render() {
    const Component = this.component;
    return (
      <div>
        <Component values={this.state.storedValues} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
}
```

I had been under the impression that useEffect and its return statement are effectively the same thing as componentDidMount and componentWillUnmount?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, this maybe late but it might help anyone end up here.

Change your 'setState(value);' to 'setState([...value]);' if it is an array, or 'setState({...value});' if it is an obj.

Answer (score -1):

> Your state is not updating as useEffect in `UseCustomHookForObservable` is just running one time. Because the hooks are called only once, so `SymbolsObservable` is not updating in your custom hooks that preventing your `useEffect` from running again.

Do it like below.

```
const useCustomHookForObservable = (initialObservable) => {
  const [storedQuotes, setQuotes] = useState({});
  const [observable, setObservable] = useState(initialObservable);
  useEffect(() => {
    observable.subscribe((value) => {
      setQuotes(value);
    });

    return () => observable.unsubscribe();
  }, [observable]);
  return {storedQuotes, setObservable}
};

function DisplayQuotes() {

  const {storedQuotes, setObservable} =  useCustomHookForObservable(SymbolsObservable);

  useEffect(() => {setObservable(SymbolsObservable)}, [SymbolsObservable])

  return (
    <div>
      <QuotesTable values={storedQuotes} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have exposed a setter function that makes sure that your `useEffect` runs as many times as `SymbolsObservable` updates.

This way is a better way to do it right.
It extracted your stateful logic from the react component, and make it look cleaner.

Comment: although this is definitely a cleaner approach (i dont believe you meant to pass in setQuotes in the displayFunction), it does not provide a solution. Im stilling logging all incomingQuotes, but state is never changed

Comment: I have updated my answer and made a few changes and added an explanation, let me know if it helps or you need more explanation around it.

Comment: it appears you changed your suggestion. let me try it...

Comment: didnt do it :(. still same behavior in that all new quotes log, but nothing sets state. what is funnier about this is that, if i set it up as a class extends Component, and put the logic in componentDidMount and use this.setState(..), all works fine

Comment: Can you ensure if your useEffect in the custom hook is running? Either use debuggers or logs. And also the value of the observable.

Comment: i put a log for value in the following from your code: useEffect(() => {
    observable.subscribe((value) => {
      setQuotes(value);
    }); 
All new quotes are logged.
I add a log add the bottom of the CustumHook for observable for storedQuotes and that logs once.
right above the return in the displayQuotes function, i put a log for storedQuotes, and it is called twice. 
The thing that strikes me as most strange is, although im logging all the new quotes in the useEffect call, setState never appears to work a line after.